# how to put a plot and a table together using grid.arrange

Tags: r

I have a plot and a table, and I would like to combine them into a plot. how should I do that.

Here is my codes:

```
df<-structure(list(AEDECOD = c("Hypoxia", "Malignant pleural effusion", 
"Decubitus ulcer", "Nausea"), ADY = c(13, 13, 13, 14)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")

tbl <-structure(list(`Analysis Relative Day` = 13, `AE Type` = "SER", 
    `Adverse Event` = "Hypoxia/Malignant pleural effusion"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

p1<- ggplot(data =df, aes(x = ADY, y = AEDECOD))+ geom_point()
p2 <-grid.arrange(p1, tbl,
nrow = 2,as.table = TRUE)

print(p2)
```

I got the error codes:

```
Error: Input must be a vector, not a <viewport> object.
```

If you know any other way to do the same thing, I would like to learn that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `ggarrange` after converting the `tibble` to `ggtexttable`

```
library(ggpubr)
ggarrange(p1, ggtexttable(tbl), nrow = 2)
```

---

Or using the OP's code

```
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p1, ggtexttable(tbl),
      nrow = 2,as.table = TRUE)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: What if I want to add a footnote `Just testing`  to plot, how should I add it? I would like to have the footnote below the table, instead of  right under plot.

Comment: @Stataq you may convert to `gt` with [tab_footnote](https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/tab_footnote.html)

Comment: Thanks. But the foot note is not really a footnote for table. more like a footnote for P2. And also how to make table align to the left?

Comment: @Stataq Can you please post as a new question. thanks

Comment: @Stataq when you say it is not a footnote, what do you mean?  I was thinkiing something like `p2 <- tbl %>% gt() %>% tab_footnote('Just texting', locations = cells_column_labels(columns = "Adverse Event"))`

Comment: just posted the new question as suggested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70219766/how-to-add-a-footnote-to-a-combined-plot