# how to adjust alignment of each element in a combined plot

Tags: r

I have a plot and a tabble, and I would like to put both into one plot with a footnote. And also how to align table to the left? and notation to the right?

My current codes are:

```
df<-structure(list(AEDECOD = c("Hypoxia", "Malignant pleural effusion", 
"Decubitus ulcer", "Nausea"), ADY = c(13, 13, 13, 14)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")

tbl <-structure(list(`Analysis Relative Day` = 13, `AE Type` = "SER", 
    `Adverse Event` = "Hypoxia/Malignant pleural effusion"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

p1<- ggplot(data =df, aes(x = ADY, y = AEDECOD, color=AEDECOD))+ 
geom_point()

tbl2<-tableGrob(tbl, rows=NULL)
p2 <-grid.arrange(p1, tbl2,
nrow = 2,as.table = TRUE,
bottom="Notation here")

print(p2)
```

My output looks like this:

[image]

Comment: package ‘bstfun’ is not available my R version. I updated the question. how can I adjust alignment of each element?

Comment: IN `patchwork` you could add `plot_spacer()` i.e. `library(patchwork);p1/ (p2 + plot_spacer() + tableGrob("Notation here"))`

Comment: Or You can have more control with `p2 <-ggtexttable(tbl);p3 <- tableGrob("Notation here");

layout <- c(
  area(t = 1, l = 1, b = 3, r = 5),
  area(t = 4, l = 1, b = 6, r = 3),
  area(t = 4, l = 6, b = 6, r = 7)
);
p1 + p2 + p3 + 
  plot_layout(design = layout)`

Comment: Let me know whether these work for you. thanks

Comment: plot_spacer() add a grey block. might need more adjustment. But that is a clever new way for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could have more control by specifying the `plot_layout` from `patchwork`

```
library(patchwork)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

p2 <- tableGrob(tbl, rows=NULL)
p3 <- tableGrob("Notation here")
layout <- c(
  area(t = 1, l = 1, b = 3, r = 5),
  area(t = 4, l = 1, b = 7, r = 3),
  area(t = 4, l = 6, b = 6, r = 7)
)
p1 + p2 + p3 + 
  plot_layout(design = layout)
```

NOTE: If we want to change the location, then we could make the changes in the value for `t`op, `b`ottom, `l`eft, `r`ight values in each of those plots - make sure that `t < b` and `l < r`

-output

[image]